# 選択されたRadioButtonによって、ViewModelのプロパティ値を変更したい。

Tags: c#, wpf

ご教授ください。

WPF上のラジオボタンで何が選択されているかViewModel側で受け取りたいです。
受け取った結果はViewModelのSelectedのプロパティに選択したRadioButtonによって、enum値を与えたいです。
ViewのRadioButtonにはまだ何もBindingしていません。

よろしくおねがいします。

ソースコードは以下の通りです。

```html
<StackPanel Name="JobSelector">
  <StackPanel.DataContext>
    <vm:JobSelectorViewModel/>
  </StackPanel.DataContext>
  <RadioButton Name="Taks1" Content="Taks1" IsChecked="True"/>
  <RadioButton Name="Taks2" Content="Taks2" IsChecked="False" />
  <RadioButton Name="Task3" Content="Task3" IsChecked="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```html
public class JobSelectorViewModel
{
  public enum TaskType { Task1, Task2, Task3}
  public TaskType Selected { get; set; }

  public JobSelectorViewModel()
  {
     //まだ何も実装してない。
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

列挙型と`bool`の変換を行う`IValueConverter`を実装するのが一般的かと思います。

```
class SomeValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Equals(value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(true.Equals(value))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

XAMLでは`TaskType`の定義を移動し、`xmlns:vm`と`someValueConverter`をリソースに登録している場合以下のようになります。

### VM

```
// XAMLから参照できるように名前空間の直下に移動する
public enum TaskType { Task1, Task2, Task3}

public class JobSelectorViewModel
{  }
```

### XAML

```
<!-- TODO: xmlns:vm="..." をルートに定義する -->
<!-- TODO: someValueConverterをリソースに定義する -->

<RadioButton
    IsChecked="{Binding Selected
                      , Converter={StaticResource someValueConverter}
                      , ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:TaskType.Task1}}"/>
```

Comment: すみません。教えてください「XAMLではTaskTypeをルートに移動し、」の部分がよくわかりません。。多分ここがわかっていないためConverterParameterの部分でエラーを受けてます。。「名前空間TaskTypeは存在しません。」と…

Comment: @KazukiSaito XAMLは基本的にネスト型に対応していないため、ViewModel内に列挙型を定義すべきではないということです。

Comment: そうなんですね。ViewModel内で列挙型はやめておきます。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。